# c# Timer method limitations

Tags: c#, system.timers.timer

We're setting up a service which can handle daily/weekly/monthly/quarterly job runs.
The issue we are facing is regarding the quarterly jobs. We just discovered that, while running our job, it fails on the `Timer()` at this point in our code:

```
_tmr = new System.Timers.Timer(lapsed);
```

where var `lapsed` lapsed ending up being over 7,500,000,000 milliseconds.

And the error was:

`Invalid valud 7,500,00,00 for parameter 'interval'`

So now that we understand the Timer() interval as per the `Timer()` definition:

`// Parameters:
     //   interval:
     //     The time, in milliseconds, between events. The value must be greater than zero
     //     and less than or equal to System.Int32.MaxValue.`

We realize that we CANNOT pass an interval value larger than `System.Int32.MaxValue` (or 2,147,483,647)

***MY PROBLEM:***

I'm trying to think of a way to simulate this quarterly "job service" functionality, while working around this millisecond interval limitation.

For example, perhaps I could flag a job for "monthly", but the logic will check the job weekly - and only execute the actual job object if we have reached the next quarter.

I'm a little stuck on this, so any guidance and/or advice is greatly appreciated....

Comment: While this has been marked as duplicate, I would like to suggest not using `System.Timers`, but consider an approach using [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

Comment: @flyte The duplicate specifically says not to use a timer, and to use a proper scheduling system.

Comment: Just set it for a day instead of a month.  Count down the days.  Easy peasy, just a variable instead of a complete library or a system service.  Do keep in mind that keeping a program running for a month requires a pretty solid electric company :)

Comment: @servy - show me where the duplicate suggests Quartz.NET as a "proper scheduling system". It doesn't, which is the whole point of my comment.

Comment: @flyte I didn't say it suggests Quartz specifically, it suggests an entirely different proper scheduling system.